# How do i count the blank lines in a python file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

i've been trying to write a function that reads a file, counts how may lines are in that file(including blank files) and writes it to a different file.

So far i've managed with reading the non-blank files and writing the amount of non-blank files to the output file, but i've been having trouble with counting blank files.

Here's what i've come up with so far,

```
input_file = None
    try:
        empty_lines = 0
        non_blank_lines = 0
        input_file = open(in_file, 'r')
        lines = input_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if not line.strip():
                empty_lines += 1
            else:
                non_blank_lines += 1
        output_file = open(out_file, "w")
        output_file.write(str(non_blank_lines + empty_lines))
        output_file.close()
    except:
        print("Whoops! looks like that file doesn't exit")
        raise IOError("exiting program now")
    finally:
        if input_file != None:
            input_file.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please fix: files vs lines vs blank files vs blank lines - you confused me as to what you want to count. Thanks

Comment: Why are you writing `str(non_blank_lines + empty_lines)`? This seems like it would print out the total number of lines in the file, as opposed to just one or the other. Did you mean to print them separately? (e.g. `.write(str(non_blank_lines) + " " + str(empty_lines))`?)

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question, i've been using input output files from the wrong folder :P.